# text followed by < character is not displaying in jsp

Tags: java, regex, jsp, jaxb

When i try to enter a text follwed by `<` character the text is not displayed as shown belowe. Using textarea field entered comments(text) like "`Test Comments with<Character`". After adding the comments to the page, comments are displaying on jsp page as:`Test Comments with` . The text missed with `<Character` This is not shown on the page. Am i need to change regular expression or did any wrong in jsp page?

Here i am using a list array to save all the comments using JSON and JAXB objects. In jsp page when i try to display the comments, those are not displaying properly. 
Commments are showing as "`Test Comments with`".

```
<td colspan="2"><html:textarea name="caseDetailForm" styleId="addCommentsTextArea"
    property="caseCommentText" style="width:99%" rows="7" styleClass="validate-length-750" />
```

Having Regular Expression like: **CommentInput =*[\w\*\-@!\.\$\+ \(\)\#\|\[\]\\/\^%&_\=~"',\<>`\}\{\:;\?*\x80\x83\xA2\xA3\xA4\xA5\xA9\xAE\r\n]***

Here list is a jaxb bean named with CaseComment. I have java code like

```
CaseComment[] list = form.getCaseDataJaxb().getCommentList();
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
JSONArray comments = new JSONArray();
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            JSONArray comments = new JSONArray();
            commObj.put(list[i].getText());
            comments.put(commObj);
            log.info("----->"+list[i].getText()+"<-----");
    }
}
obj.put("comData", comments);
response.setContentType("text/json");
response.getWriter().write(obj.toString());
```

After debugging in java , i am getting the entire text "`Test Comments with<Character`" in the `list`. But not showing in jsp.

to display in jsp i am using the below tags:

```
<logic:iterate id="comments" name="InfoForm" property="caseDataJaxb.commentList" indexId="index">
 <tr>
    <td><c:out value="${comments.text}"/></td>
 </tr>
</logic:iterate>
```

Comment: i dont know if this helps but at the end of your <td> tag you did /><td>. change that to </td>

Comment: If you want to display `<` you must replace it with his htmlentity.

Comment: @Cas: OP is using `<c:out>` to display it.

Comment: @BalusC : do you have any idea. Here i can see the comments in java file in debugging. But jsp is not displaying whole comments with < character. Do i need to change any RegEx or Jsp?

Comment: You should replace `<` with htmlentity before showing this to a user, in order to avoid XSS -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes. i found the answer to my problem and as per [cheffe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2160152/cheffe) said i did in the same way.

Here is the logic:

```
CaseComment[] list = form.getCaseDataJaxb().getCommentList();
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
JSONArray comments = new JSONArray();
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray comments = new JSONArray();
    String str = list[i].getText());
    str = str.replaceAll("<","&amp;");  
    commObj.put(str);
    comments.put(commObj);
    }
}
obj.put("comData", comments);
response.setContentType("text/json");
response.getWriter().write(obj.toString());
```

i changed the code like this and found the solution. Also code got enhanced by other in [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/35835/assigning-list-index-values-to-string/35838#35838).